# Empty data when sending a button value from HTML to Flask through Ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post

I am trying to send the value of the button clicked in HTML to a Flask function through an Ajax [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

I spend multiple hours trying to find minimal working examples of POST to Flask, but I didn't find anything really minimal. This is the minimal working example that I created after many stack overflows. This is my HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div>
            <button value="btn1">Button1</button>
            <button value="btn2">Button2</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/process',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data : {'search' : value}
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

And this is my Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    value = request.get_json()
    print(value)
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

I use the *print(value)* as a debug check. When I click the button, I receive in the terminal an error 400 `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jul/2023 03:04:49] "POST /process HTTP/1.1" 400 -` but if I try to use `request.form`, I get an empty value, but the correct key `ImmutableMultiDict([('search', '')])`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript code, you are using `$this.val()` to retrieve the value of the clicked button. However, `$this` refers to the current document, not the clicked button itself. To fix this, update your event handler to target the button elements correctly. Finished version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div>
        <button class="my-button" value="btn1">Button1</button>
        <button class="my-button" value="btn2">Button2</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my-button').on('click', function(event) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/process',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({'search': value}), // Convert to JSON string
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

In the modified code, I added the class `"my-button"` to the buttons to make it easier to target them in jQuery. Then, I updated the event handler to use `$'.my-button'` to select the buttons and bind the `click` event to them.

In your Flask app, you can access the value sent from the HTML page using `request.form['search']`. Here's the updated Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    value = request.form['search']
    print(value)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Success'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

I also added jsonify to the response to convert it to JSON format. This is optional, but it's good practice to send JSON responses when working with AJAX requests. JSON is also used a lot in use with data.

It should work now.

Comment: the code as is, throws me a "400 Bad Request" error given by the request.form. If I change it back to get_json() works great! thanks

Comment: Another little note, if you want the HTML page to update in case you are returning `return render_template()` in flask, the `success` line in the ajax has to be this: `success: function(response){document.write(response);}`